# i try ajax partial refresh html,but it does't work

Tags: javascript, django, ajax

I'm trying to load the page locally with Ajax, but the following code doesn't work.
My idea is to pass the 'MSG' information of 'views' to Ajax and refresh the page locally without loading the entire page. If the input does not meet the requirements, the front end rejects the submission and gives a prompt message.

views.py

```
def login(request):
    hashkey = CaptchaStore.generate_key()
    image_url = captcha_image_url(hashkey)
    captcha = {'image_url': image_url, 'hashkey':hashkey}
    if request.POST:
        username = request.POST['username']
        password = request.POST['password']
        key = request.POST['hashkey']
        capt = request.POST['captcha']
        if username and password:
            if captchautil.is_valid(capt, key):
                user = auth.authenticate(username=username, password=password)
                human = True
                if user:
                    auth.login(request, user)
                    return redirect('/')
                else:
                    msg = '用户名密码错误'
            else:
                msg = '请输入正确的验证码'
        else:
            msg = '请输入用户名与密码'
        return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
    return render(request, 'login.html', locals())
```

login.html

```
{% block content %}
<div id="login" class="login">
<form action="/login/" method="post" class="navbar-form">
{% csrf_token %}
<div id="input" class="form-group">
<input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="请输入手机号或邮箱" id='user' title="请输入手机号或邮箱"><br><br>
<input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="密码" id='pwd' title="请输入密码"><br><br>
<img src="{{image_url}}" alt='验证码' id='id_captcha'>
<span><a href="#" id="refresh_captcha">看不清验证码？刷新</a></span>
<br>
<input  id='captcha' placeholder="请输入验证码" name="captcha" class="form-control" type="text" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="请输入验证码">
<input value="{{hashkey}}" type="hidden" name="hashkey" id='hashkey'>
<br>
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary form-control" name="click" id='click'>登录</button>
</div>
<p style="margin-left: auto;" id="msg">{{ msg }}</p></div>
</form>

<div style="margin-left: 3%">
<span>
<a href="">忘记密码了?</a>
</span>
<span style="margin-left: 3%"><a href="/regist/">免费注册</a></span>
</div>
</div>
{% endblock %}

{% block lastscript %}
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    //刷新验证码
    $('#refresh_captcha').click(function(){
        $.getJSON("/refresh_captcha/", function(result){
            $('#id_captcha').attr('src', result['image_url']);
            $('#hashkey').val(result['hashkey'])
        });
    });
});
$(function(){
    $("#click").submit(function(){
        var username = $("#user").val();
        var password = $("#pwd").val();
        var captcha = $("#captcha").val();
        var key = $("#hashkey").val();
        $(this).ajaxSubmit({
            type:'post',
            url: '/login/',
            dataType: 'text',
            data:{'username':username, "password":password, "capt":captcha, "key":key},
            success:function(msg){
                $("#msg").html(msg);
            }
        });
        return false;       
    })
})
</script>
{% endblock %}
```

I didn't find out where the problem was. Please help me if you know

Answer (score 1):

If you are fetching form dynamically and if you are trying to say like your javascript click functions are not working then you should try below.

```
 $(document).on("click","#test-element",function() {
});
```

instead of **normal click or submit** an event
 $("#click").submit(function(){ }); .

As per my knowledge if you are creating dynamic elements then the normal click event of jquery will not work. you need to write click event what added above.